# HTML/CSS hover not working as intended

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make it so on hover, a `div` blurs and then another `div` appears on top of it.

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vmqmbx94/

Snippet:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,500);

/*
  pad the body and set default font styles
*/
body {
 font: 300 16px/1.2 Lato;
 background-image: url('resource/images/witewall_3.png');
}

.menu {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}
/*
  navigation
*/
.nav {
 list-style: none;
 font-size: 20px;
}

/*
  nav list items
  1. side by side
  2. needed for circle positioning
*/
.nav li {
 float: left; /*1*/
}

/*
  nav link items
*/
.nav>li a {
 display: block; /*1*/
 padding: 12px 18px; /*2*/
 text-decoration: none; /*3*/
 color: #999; /*4*/
 transition: all ease .5s;
}

/*
  fade out all links on ul hover
*/
.nav:hover>li a {
 opacity: .5;
 transition: all ease .5s;
}

/*
  override previous rule to highlight current link
*/
.nav>li:hover a {
 opacity: 1;
 color: #E74C3C;
 border-color: #E74C3C;
}

.container {
 width: 1500px;
 height: 800px;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.games {
 width: 400px;
 height: 300px;
 float: left;
 background-image: url('resource/images/ryu_sfv.jpg');
 background-size: 600px;
 background-position: 50%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 90px #999, inset 5px 0 10px #999, inset -5px 0
  10px #999, inset 5px 0 10px #999, inset -5px 0 40px #999, 0 0 50px
  #999, -5px 0 0px #999, 5px 0 0px #999;
 -webkit-transition: width 3s; /* Safari */
 -webkit-transition-delay: 1s; /* Safari */
 transition: .3s;
}

.games:hover {
 filter: blur(5px);
 -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
 -moz-filter: blur(5px);
 -o-filter: blur(5px);
 -ms-filter: blur(5px);
 -o-filter: blur(5px);
}

.games:hover .title {
 diplay: block;
}

.title {
 width: 400px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: white;
 margin-top: 250px;
 text-align: center;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="./">Home</a><i class="circle"></i></li>
    <li><a href="./games">Games</a></li>
    <li><a href="./players">Players</a></li>
    <li><a href="">News</a></li>
    <li style="float: right">
      <a href="./login">Login/Sign up</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="games">
    <div class="title">STREET FIGHTER</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you see, the div blurs on hover, but the other one does not appear on hover at all.

I'm trying to make the class `games` to blur and the class `title` to appear, but no blurred.

How can I make it to have my desired results? What am I doing wrong?

PS: I don't know how to edit HTML/CSS questions, so if someone wants to adjust my code blocks, go ahead.

Comment: Don´t understand what you need.

Comment: As I check your fiddle your `display` was wrong spelling `.games:hover .title`

Comment: You have a typo: `"diplay"` instead of `"display"`. But even with it you'll still get  not very good result - title is also blurred.

Comment: This is so embarrassing that I kind want to delete this question now haha

Comment: This kind of questions should be closed as offtopic > typographycal error. Don't feed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in you css `diplay: block;` you are missing a s.

Comment: Typo should be commented :)

Comment: Typo is the reason it doesn't work, this is the right answer.

Comment: There are no right answer in an offtopic question, that should be closed as typograpyhcal error

Answer (score 2):

The answer @Ales provided fixes your problem and I upvote that answer because it's what you were asking. BUT I'm not sure if you want the title to be blurred or not, but if not you can play with z-indexes like in the link below (I'm bored and fiddled with your code just for fun).

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5s33ckzz/

Basically just change some html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="games"></div>
    <div class="title">STREET FIGHTER</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And set the z-indexes as in the fiddle.

Comment: Wow yes this also solves my problem. I never knew the existence of `z-index` I'll now look that up

Comment: Well, that's just great that you can learn so much from just one post on SO. Really nice to hear :)